# Where does images go after user uploads? - Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, magento-community, helper, user-roles

I'm having an issue with the Upload feature (Magento 1.7) on Magento custom options. I'm not able to find images after customer uploads. It's nowhere to be found when I check Magento backend and my FTP account. I've checked all folders in my /media directory and can't find anything :-( Please help or advise if you can. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you upload file using Custom option the it will store in below path.

`Your Root Folder/media/custom_options/quote` folder

If File is not uploading then must check your folder permission.

Hope you got the Answers.

Comment: Thank you for immediate response. I'm not able to find files in my .../quote folder. The permissions are set to 777.

Comment: check media folder permission

Comment: I noticed the media folder was set to 777. I also the custom_options folder set to 777